# Centralized Free Open Source Logs monitoring tool

Tags: linux, windows, monitoring

I have a small question.

Is there a Free Open Source Monitoring tool which I can install on one system that can collect the logs of both Linux and Windows and store & Display on Central Server.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you are not suppose to ask for applications recommendations here.
You can ask them at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Anyway, I've found two:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/nxlog-ce/?source=recommended
http://sourceforge.net/projects/snare/?source=recommended